# Plot 2 Dataframes in one Figure in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hey I want to plot 2 DataFrames in one Figure in Pandas.

My DataFrame(s) look like this(excerpt from DataFrame):

```
       Timestamp  Distance     Speed  Heart Rate   Pace
1          0.0      3.02  2.353079          89  425.0
2          1.0      5.10  1.847000          92  541.0
3          2.0      7.48  1.969000          96  508.0
4          4.0     14.13  2.902000          93  345.0
5         10.0     28.01  2.967000          96  337.0
6         11.0     30.96  2.995000         101  334.0
7         12.0     33.79  2.995000         104  334.0
8         13.0     36.56  2.967000         114  337.0
```

They both have different number of items but otherwise have the same format.

[Right now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z475P.png)

and I am plotting it with this code.

```
ax = dataframe1[['Speed','Heart Rate','Pace']].plot(subplots=True,
                                               title=['Speed in m/s','Heart Rate in bmp','Pace in min/km',],
                                               x=dataframe1['Timestamp'],)
```

What I want to do now is to plot the HeartRate from DateFrame2 in the same subplot as the HeartRate from DataFrame1 (in a different color) but I don't know how .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5);

x = dataframe1.set_index('Timestamp').rename_axis(None)    
x['Speed'].plot(ax=axes[0], title='Speed in m/s', legend=True)
x['Heart Rate'].plot(ax=axes[1], title='Heart Rate in bmp', legend=True)
x['Pace'].plot(ax=axes[2], title='Pace in min/km', legend=True)
```

Simulating `dataframe1['Heart Rate'] * 2` as `dataframe2['HeartRate']`:

```
x[['Heart Rate']].rename(columns={'Heart Rate':'Heart Rate2'}).mul(2).plot(ax=axes[1], legend=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked but for some reason the x axis is now the index of the Dataframe and not the values from `dataframe1['Timestamp']` even though it works when I use my code from above to plot it.

Comment: How would I use dataframe 2 now? If I just use `dataframe2['Heart Rate'].plot(ax=axes[1])` then dataframe 1 plots nicely but for dataframe2 the  index is still used instead of the Timestamp. Nevermind figured it out. Using `x2 = dataframe2.set_index('Timestamp').rename_axis(None)` and then `x2['Heart Rate'].plot(ax=axes[1])`

Comment: does `dataframe2` has the same length as `dataframe1`?

Comment: No they don't have the same length but I figured it out (see edit of comment above). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `join` the dataframes then:

```
dataframe1['Heart Rate2'] = dataframe2['Heart Rate']
dataframe1[['Speed','Heart Rate','Pace', 'Heart Rate2']].plot()
```

Comment: Okay thanks but how would I get both Heart Rates( 1 and 2) to show up in the same subplot?